# SQL Query joining inner selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I am probably doing this the wrong way... but here's what I've got... it's an Oracle instance with a data model like so:

```
TABLE 1
-----------
ID | NAME |
-----------

TABLE 2
----------------------------------------------
ID | NAME | TABLE_1_ID | TIMESTAMP | SOME_NUM
----------------------------------------------

TABLE 3
-----------------------
ID | NAME | TABLE_1_ID
-----------------------
```

I'd like a query that gives me 4 columns:

- t1.name
- a count of all entries in table 2 where SOME_NUM = 1 and t1.id = t2.table_1_id
- a count of all entries in table 2 where TIMESTAMP is between two values and t1.id = t2.table_1_id
- a count of all entries in table 3 where t1.id = t3.table_1_id

I expect Table 1 to be small compared to the other two tables.

Here's what I did to generate the first two sets:

```
select t1.name, a.count
from 
   ( select TABLE_1_ID, COUNT(*) count
     from TABLE_2
     group by TABLE_1_ID
   ) a,
table_1 t1
where t1.id = a.table_1_id
```

This worked... but when I try to get the third column, this fails.

```
select t1.name, a.count, b.count2
from 
   ( select TABLE_1_ID, COUNT(*) count
     from TABLE_2
     group by TABLE_1_ID
   ) a,
   ( select TABLE_1_ID, COUNT(*) count2
     from TABLE_2
     where TIMESTAMP < ? and TIMESTAMP > ?
     group by TABLE_1_ID
   ) b,

table_1 t1
where t1.id = a.table_1_id and t1.id = b.table_1_id
```

This doesn't return any entries that do not satisfy the where clause regarding timestamps.  If I change the and to an or, I get repeated t1.names.

I'm not very good at SQL as you can tell.  I think it's doing an inner join here, but I think I want an outer join since I would like a result set with the same number of rows as TABLE_1.  I don't even want to try for the 4th result until understanding how to properly get the third.

Comment: +1 For a well explained question. Haven't got time to look at it now and I don't have Oracle. However I think this should be do-able in vanilla SQL and I'm sure someone will sus it by the time I'm getting up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is suggestion that the 2nd form is preferable, but for all things performance, that depends on your data - use what works best for you

#### Option 1:

Instead of JOINs, simply present them as subqueries that present a scalar value for the columns.

i.e. up to 3rd column

```
select
   t1.name,
   ( select COUNT(*)
     from TABLE_2 a
     WHERE a.TABLE_1_ID = t1.ID
   ) a_count,
   ( select COUNT(*)
     from TABLE_2 b
     where b.TIMESTAMP < ? and b.TIMESTAMP > ?
       AND t1.id = b.table_1_id
   ) b_count

from table_1 t1
```

This requires N x C subselects, one for each row in t1 against each column.

That works reasonably if the tables are not too large, or if each subquery has a good index on table_1_id so that the total subquery visits do not exceed the number of rows of a full table scan.  Remember that a count(*) query can satisfied directly from index pages without looking up actual table data, so it is quite fast.

#### Option 2:

Perform a single pass on each table involved, and LEFT JOIN them together.

```
select t1.name, nvl(a.count1,0) count1, nvl(b.count2,0) count2
from table_1 t1
left join
   ( select TABLE_1_ID, COUNT(*) count1
     from TABLE_2
     group by TABLE_1_ID
   ) a ON t1.id = a.table_1_id
left join
   ( select TABLE_1_ID, COUNT(*) count2
     from TABLE_2
     where TIMESTAMP < ? and TIMESTAMP > ?
     group by TABLE_1_ID
   ) b ON t1.id = b.table_1_id
```

The left join subselects (grouped by TABLE_1_ID) ensures either 1 row for a TABLE1.ID, or no rows.  This prevents Cartesian products occuring.  Now you can get the counts, but `NVL` is added because in this form, it is possible for count to be returned as NULL.

In the first form shown, count is never NULL.

Comment: it's really easy to understand- how does it perform?

Comment: May I suggest that you promote 'another option' to the first part of the answer, and relegate what is currently listed first to 'an inferior alternative that helped generate the suggested answer'...or even just delete the first half, if you prefer.  Cautious use of '###' and labels may make it easy.  Your comment about 'it has to fire one subquery per column per row' has been incorporated into the text for the (current) first answer, which is good - I'd remove the comment itself.

Comment: I'm happy with it as is. The first form performs reasonably well in quite a few DBMS I work with, since as stated - the index seeks and aggregation never touch the table data, if proper indexes are in place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   SELECT t1.NAME,  
          SUM(CASE 
                WHEN t2.some_num = 1 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
              END),
          SUM(CASE 
                WHEN t2.timestamp BETWEEN SYSDATE-1 AND SYSDATE+1 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
              END),
          t3.cnt
     FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.table_1_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT table_1_id, 
                  COUNT(1) cnt 
             FROM table3 
         GROUP BY table_1_id) t3 ON t1.id = t3.table_1_id
 GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: +1: That's what I was going to post, with the exception that I'd LEFT JOIN to tables 2 & 3 because an inner join will return only records in table 1 that exist in tables 2 & 3 -- not either or.  Beyond that, always better than using correlated subselects for the sake of the correlation.

Comment: how does this perform compared to the other answer?  Also.. can you explain this a bit more?  I'm lost on how the SUM clauses know its looking at table2 (is that the Inner join?)

Comment: @OMG Ponies - do you mean to change both INNER JOIN statements to LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @OMG: I assumed both the tables 2&3 to have the records for every record in table1. Changed the query to handle other scenario. Thx

Comment: @Cyberkiwi: I think this form would fare well compared to two queries with group by in each of them. May be I am missing something. Can you pls help me understand?

Comment: Apologies, did not notice that you already joined to table3.  It is a good specific solution (rewrite of subqueries).  But doesn't show how one would expand on the pattern.  It needs a GROUP BY anyway.